# HTML5 Required validation not showing

Tags: asp.net, html

I know there are a lot of questions about this but none of the answers solve my problem.

I am trying to implement the required validation which is built into html5, however when i press my submit button and leave the field blank nothing happens.

my html:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <form action="" method="post">
  <div>
          <div style="margin-right:230px;float:right;">
            <div style="padding-left: 10px; font-size: 13px; padding-top: 30px; font-weight: bold;
                color: black">
                <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Caller Number"></asp:Label></div>
            <div id="div3" tabindex="1" class="ui-widget">
             <input required="required"  style="width: 180px;margin-left:8px;" id="txtCallerNumber" 
                              type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

       <button  type="submit" id="btnSave" style="margin:30px;width:70px;">Save</button>
  </form>
</asp:Content>
```

I have also tried calling submitForm() on the form submit event

I am developing for IE11

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Webforms? If so, the framework will wrap your entire page in a `<form>` tag and since you're not allowed to nest `<form>`s the browser will ignore the innermost one. Also, do you have any javascript associated with the `<button>`?

Comment: @xec I am yes, i figured that as my re sharper was complaining so i moved my main content placeholder in the Site.Master, out of the form tags. This page is only nested in one form tag. Nope i don't have any JS associated with the button.

Comment: @DNKROZ your HTML works in IE 11.0.9600.17126 http://jsfiddle.net/mBdJ4/1/

Comment: @FabianMebus You are right - that works. it must be some of my dodgy javascript somewhere then. Nevermind, I've implemented a different solution. (The message box in IE11 is kinda ugly anyway)